# Help Decoding JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

I'm trying to get the "screenshotUrls" string from this piece of json:

```
$request_url = 'http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=ibooks&country=us&entity=software&limit=1';
$json = file_get_contents($request_url);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);

echo $decode['results'][0]['screenshotUrls'];
```

But I get only text "Array"

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `$decode['results'][0]['screenshotUrls']` is probably an array and not a string. Do a `var_dump($decode);` to see what it looks like.

Comment: Have a look at [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$decode['results']['0']['screenshotUrls']` is an array, if you want just a string (say, delimited by commas), you could use

```
echo implode(",", $decode['results']['0']['screenshotUrls']);
```

This will iterate over the array, and return a comma-separated string of all the URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var_dump($decode['results'][0]['screenshotUrls']);
```

IF you get 'Array' output by PHP that means that you're trying to echo an actual array (or the string 'Array'...). That means you need to get a specific index value.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `var_dump($decode['results']['0']['screenshotUrls'])`. You'll find that the `['screenshotUrls']` is actually an Array, containing one or more URLs (hence the plural 'urls' in its name).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code so far, but `$decode['results'][0]['screenshotUrls']` is an array of all the URLs to screenshots. To go through each one individualy, you need to do:

```
forearch ($decode['results'][0]['screenshotUrls'] as $url) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```